# Why does performing any translation on parent bone move entire mesh?

Tags: armature, bones

I have a 3d model of a  snake thing. The snake thing has bunch of bones in a line. All on the bones are parented to the bone at the front of the line.
[image]

I would like for the first bone to only move the head part of the mesh.

Comment: You need to setup IK spline to control the head independently of children. Search for some tutorials for IK spline.

Answer (score 1):

Because the parent bone moves all the other bones, and (I'm assuming) those bones are all weight painted to modify the mesh via an Armature modifier.  Is there a particular issue that you have with this setup, or another goal you have for this?